# Error in my code using Craven command

Tags: r

Hi guys I'm using to solve the following using R:

[image]

I've coded to following script in R but the last 2 lines have given errors that I don't know how to fix in order to progress.

```
craven<-read.csv("cystfibr.csv")
craven
attach(craven)
Pemax
cor(craven)
round(cor(craven),2)
Model2<-lm(Pemax~Age+Sex+Height+Weight+Bmp+Fev1+Rv+Frc+Tlc)
summary(Model2)
```

Note 'cystfibr.csv' is the following in excel and saved on my documents

[image]

Comment: If you include some section of `craven` using `dput(head(craven, 10))` and the errors you're seeing, we can begin to offer help.  Without those two things, it will be speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not use attach() unless you know what it does - use for example the `data` argument of lm().

Looking at your excel-sheet it looks like your variable names are all lowercase, however in you model specification the names start with an uppercase letter. This might cause the error (which error?).